# Python: AttributeError when checking if properties exist

Tags: python, attributeerror

I have a logging class that allows a prefix to be added to the logs. If there is no prefix given, it should default to "".

```
class PrefixedLog(Loggable):
    def __init__(self):
        self._prefix = None

    @property
    def prefix(self):
        if self._prefix:
            return self._prefix
        else:
            return ""

    @prefix.setter
    def prefix(self, value):
        self._prefix = value

    @property
    def log(self):
        if not hasattr(self, '_log') or not self._log:
            log = logging.getLogger(self.__class__.__name__)
            self._log = LoggerAdapter(self._prefix, log)
        return self._log
```

I have another class, which then creates an object of another class where I'm trying to set the prefix:

```
class A(PrefixedLog):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(A, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.b = B()
```

The class with the prefix:

```
class B(PrefixedLog):
    self.another_class = AnotherClass()
    if self.prefix:
        self.another_class.prefix = 'desired prefix'
```

I'm getting this error:

```
AttributeError: 'B' object has no attribute '_prefix'
```

on the

```
if self.prefix:
```

line.

I've searched for solutions already but most had to do with formatting issues...I've made sure there are no tabs.  Any ideas on what the problem might be? Thanks in advance.

Also - I want to make sure that even if a class doesn't specifically set a prefix, then the prefix does default to "" without any errors, ie I don't have to go back to every class I have and set the prefix.

Comment: [`hasattr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=hasattr#hasattr)`(self,"_prefix")`

Comment: Do you not need to call super as prefix is a property of the parent?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

When you write `self._prefix` it retrieves the value of the attribute, if the attribute doesn't exist it raises an `AttributeError`.  In this case you want to be checking whether the attribute exists or not which is what [`hasattr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=hasattr#hasattr) is for:

```
if hasattr(self,"_prefix"):
    return self._prefix
else:
    return ''
```

However this can be shortened with a fallback value for [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=hasattr#getattr)

```
return getattr(self,"_prefix", '')
```

Comment: @R.J after seeing JustinBuchanan's answer and noticing that you are in fact initializing `self._prefix = None` but never calling that super method I'd expect this to produce the wrong result if making an instance of `A` (self.prefix -> None)

Answer (score 5):

Did you mean to put the code in class `B` inside of an `__init__()` method? I think this code:

```
class B(PrefixedLog):
    self.another_class = AnotherClass()
    if self.prefix:
        self.another_class.prefix = 'desired prefix'
```

Should be changed to:

```
class B(PrefixedLog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.another_class = AnotherClass()
        if self.prefix:
            self.another_class.prefix = 'desired prefix'
```

Comment: You'd still need to call `super()` before checking `self.prefix` though.

Comment: That was clearly a typo, otherwise the error would be `NameError: name 'self' is not defined`

Comment: Yeah, you're right.  I think the main issue is that the superclass initializer wasn't being called as Daniel pointed out, so `_prefix` never got set in the first place.